# Required icon sizes for tvOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, icons, tvos, apple-tv

What sizes (resolution) Icons I need to use for tvOS build?

[image]

After some reading, I found following resolutions but can't able to decide which one to use at which place?

**App Icon** Small Icon - 400x240, Large Icon - 1280x768

**Top Self Image** 1920x720

Comment: Note however now that the 4K models exist, the top shelf image is TWICE that size, AND there's a new Wide one  :/

Answer (score 0):

The icons require three different images to achieve the parallax effect. The sizes you mention in your question are correct. For more information refer to the Apple TV [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/).

Comment: Means layer wise I need to enter same image that belongs to that category. How many layers images are needed?